# How to sum specific element in reduce object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Lets say I have this array of objects:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  { task: "work", time: 1 }, 
  { task: "travel", time: 4 }, 
  { task: "work", time: 5 }, 
  { task: "eat", time: 3 }, 
  { task: "eat", time: 1 }, 
  { task: "eat", time: 5 }
];
```

and I want to return a single objects that returns each key as the task and each value as the sum of all values of the key.
for example, the produced object of the array above should be:

```
sumOfObejcts = {
  work: 6,
  travel: 4,
  eat: 9
}
```

How can I do it properly with reduce function?
I don't know how to sum all the items of specific key, this is what I made after few tries from examples:

```
    const sumOfObejcts = arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, items) => {
      let { task, time } = items;
      return { ...acc, [task]: [...(acc[task] || []), time] };
    }, {});
```

and the output I get is:

```
{
  work: [1, 5],
  travel: [4],
  eat: [3, 1, 5]
}
```

So, I just want to return the sum of occurrence of the value instead.

Comment: Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve.  (I did not downvote you)

Comment: Are you okay using a utility library like underscore or loadsh?  Lot's of useful stuff in these, including a function called _.groupBy() which is 90% of what you're looking for

Comment: Hey, No, I want to do it without external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is very close; except that you're creating array of values on each iteration, instead of summing the current time values.

Here I've changed the value you assign to the key by using a ternary statement.  This checks to see if the task exists in the accumulator object; if the task already exists, that means there is already a sum for this task and thus we just need to add on the current time to the existing sum.  Otherwise, if the accumulator object doesn't have the task, the value will be primed using the current task's time.

```js
const sumOfObjects = arrayOfObjects
  .reduce((acc, item) =>
    ({ ...acc, [item.task]: (
       acc[item.task] // does the task exist in the accumulator object?
       ? acc[item.task] + item.time // if so, set a value equal to the current task's time plus the existing value
       : item.time // otherwise, prime the task's value to the current time
      ) })
  , {});
```

Comment: Thanks! another little question, can I add more keys to the object (from another object for example) in the same object of reduce func?

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` and build the object

```js
const sumOfObjects = (arr, all = {}) => (
  arr.forEach(({ task, time }) => (all[task] = (all[task] ?? 0) + time)), all
);

const arrayOfObjects = [
  { task: "work", time: 1 },
  { task: "travel", time: 4 },
  { task: "work", time: 5 },
  { task: "eat", time: 3 },
  { task: "eat", time: 1 },
  { task: "eat", time: 5 },
];

console.log(sumOfObjects(arrayOfObjects));
```